# Can multiple cities work the same tile in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

Can multiple cities work the same tile in Civilization 5?

For example, if I have found a natural wonder, can I found my early settlers around it, so that they are four hex away from each other and all work the same tile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, a tile may only be worked by a single city on any given turn.

If you tell a city to work a specific tile that another city is already using then the other city will be forced to stop working it. It is possible to get the other city to start working the tile again (but only by stopping the new city from doing so) - the tile is never "locked" to a particular city.

You should determine what bonus output the wonder has and then try to work it from a city that takes the most advantage of that - so if you have a gold-generating wonder, let a gold-generating city work the tile, for example.